# How do I display a number as $#,### in SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, number-formatting

The field is set to MONEY.

I want to select [field_name] as $#,###.

I tried

```
SELECT CAST([field_name] AS DECIMAL (1, 3))
FROM ...
```

but no luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720454/tsql-casting-to-money-rounds-up) ... [Additional Resource](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/displaying-money-values-in-currency-format-in-sql/5803705)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @v money
set @v = 1234.567 
select '$' + parsename(convert(varchar(20), @v, 1), 2)
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/4177)

Answer (score 2):

There is a money data type, however it will not prefix the "money" with a currency sign. You would need to 
    SELECT '$' + Cast(CAST([field_name] AS DECIMAL (1, 3)) AS VARCHAR(4))
however you really should avoid this approach. Formatting should really be done exclusively in the UI, then the UI should know the country and consequentially the currency symbol 
The money data type allows you to add, (SUM aggregate) stuff without loosing small change, which a floating numeric data type will do under fairly simple cirumstances.

HTH

Ian

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

> http://www.techrepublic.com/article/displaying-money-values-in-currency-format-in-sql/5803705
>
> The reader also wanted to know how to get the currency sign prepended
>   to the amount, e.g., $1,320.00.
>
> ```
> SELECT 
>     Quantity, 
>     '$' + CONVERT(varchar(12), Unitprice, 1) AS Unitprice, 
>     '$' + CONVERT(varchar(12), Quantity * UnitPrice, 1) AS Amount 
>  FROM [Order Details]
> ```

Comment: this is giving me numbers such as $25,000.00. It needs to be: $25,000. how do I get rid of the last 2 0's?

Comment: You can use "replace": `select replace(convert(varchar,cast(Quantity * UnitPrice, 1), '.00',''))`